# Execute function depending on tag

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RpWeNzfSUHw&list=RDCMUCbXgNpp0jedKWcQiULLbDTA&start_radio=1&rv=RpWeNzfSUHw&t=2) and am using `PyTorch` to implement intelligent responses for my bot, there is a JSON file with intents and each intent contains a tag, pattern, response. The model predicts the tag based on the patterns and then returns a response of that respective tag. So far the bot works fine, I want it to execute a function based on the predicted tag. For example, if the tag is `bye` I want the bot to execute `sys.exit(0)`

JSON file

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "tag": "thanks",
      "patterns": ["Thanks", "Thank you", "That's helpful", "Thank's a lot!"],
      "responses": ["Happy to help!", "Any time!", "My pleasure"]
    },
    {
      "tag": "bye",
      "patterns": ["Ok bye", "See you later", "good bye"],
      "responses": ["Nice talking with you", "Later!"]
    }
  ]
}
```

main script

```
if response.count(wakeCommand) > 0:
    speak("Yes boss")
    response = takeCommand()

    sentence = tokenize(response)
    X = bag_of_words(sentence, all_words)
    X = X.reshape(1, X.shape[0])
    X = torch.from_numpy(X).to(device)

    output = model(X)
    _, predicted = torch.max(output, dim=1)

    tag = tags[predicted.item()]

    probs = torch.softmax(output, dim=1)
    prob = probs[0][predicted.item()]

    if prob.item() > 0.75:
        for intent in intents['intents']:
            if tag == intent["tag"]:
                speak(f"{random.choice(intent['responses'])}")
                        
            elif tag == 'bye':
                speak(f"{random.choice(intent['responses'])}")
                sys.exit(0)
```

The problem is when the tag is predicted it executes the function multiple times because it is in a for loop and also it does not respond with the expected response

Comment: I don't know how works your code but you can use `break` to exit `for`-loop before end of data.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.